# validate the form using javascript where i have from and to date picker and it should allow only current date and valid time not the next day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a form where have to enter from and to date in date picker , but while saving the data the from date and to date should be for the current date. And if i enter to date as tomorrows date it should not allow to save the date.Kindly let me know as how to do this in javascript. May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? And even say from time is 10 AM then to time should be 12 pm like not less than from time . Please advice in achieving this using javascript

Comment: from and to Should be Current day only?

Comment: ok i added the answer

Comment: you create jsfiddle ,what u tried ? or u did nothing research just  want readymade answer?

Comment: boss! dont need your answer.. we come here for doubts if we know everything why will i ask

Comment: i am a fresher not an expert and u dont have rights to speak like this

Answer (score 0):

```
 var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: today,
    endDate: lastDate,

});

var counter=0;

$("#datepicker").change(function(){
    var date1 = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
date1=date1.getDate();

if(today.getDate() != date1)
{
    if(counter%2==0)
    alert("please select current date");
}
counter++;
});
```

Check working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GX82L/15/

Done as per your expectation ,like it should prompt if other than current date is selected

Comment: can u validate means if the other date is entered except current it should give an alert Invalid date

Comment: but i have two date pickers from date and to date

Comment: Then what ? one will be datepicker and second will be as datepicker1 .Do programming(copy paste the above code) just replace in 2nd code datepicker by datepicker1. Do u understand ?

Comment: Use         $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    startDate: today,
    endDate: lastDate,

});

var counter=0;

$("#datepicker1").change(function(){
    var date1 = $("#datepicker1").datepicker('getDate');
date1=date1.getDate();

if(today.getDate() != date1)
{
    if(counter%2==0)
    alert("please select current date");
}
counter++;
});