# how to validate date in javascript which allows only same date for both from and to date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i have a form where i have 2 date time pickers from date and to date , my requirement is if the from date selected is 17-4-2014 then to date has to be also on the same date. It should not allow 18 or any other dates. Also it should validate time where to time cannot be less than from time . Kindly help me in fixing this issue using javascript

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use 1 date picker if you only want 1 date?

Comment: i need two date pickers one for from date and the other for to date

Comment: possible duplicate of [validate the form using javascript where i have from and to date picker and it should allow only current date and valid time not the next day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128695/validate-the-form-using-javascript-where-i-have-from-and-to-date-picker-and-it-s)

Comment: This user already Posted same Question here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128695/validate-the-form-using-javascript-where-i-have-from-and-to-date-picker-and-it-s    Why do u ask same Question and waste our time ?

Comment: possible duplicate of validate the form using javascript where i have from and to date picker and it should allow only current date and valid time not the next day

Comment: you dont have to waste your time boss

Comment: i asked cuz your response was not belonging to the question which i asked. Expecting others to answer not you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(function(){
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker(
                {dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                minDate: '-60Y', maxDate: '+0Y',
                yearRange: '-60:+20',
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: '/cpf/images/datepicker.gif',
                buttonImageOnly: true
                }
                );
    });
         $(function(){
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker(
                {dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                minDate: '-60Y', maxDate: '+0Y',
                yearRange: '-60:+20',
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: '/cpf/images/datepicker.gif',
                buttonImageOnly: true
                }
                );
    });

<TD align="right" width="10%"><strong>Service Date From</strong></TD>
        <TD width="16%"><input id="datepicker1" name="check_in_from" class="input_style4" type="text" readonly value="{$form.check_in_from|date_format:" %d-%b-%Y"}" style="width: 160px;"> <img src="images/clear.gif" alt="clear" title="clear" onclick="clear1('datepicker1')"></td>
        <TD align="right" width="11%"><strong>Service Date To</strong></TD>
        <TD width="16%"><input id="datepicker2" name="check_in_to" class="input_style4" type="text" readonly value="{$form.check_in_to|date_format:" %d-%b-%Y"}" style="width: 160px;"> <img src="images/clear.gif" alt="clear" title="clear" onclick="clear1('datepicker2')"></TD>
```

Comment: This user already Posted same Question here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128695/validate-the-form-using-javascript-where-i-have-from-and-to-date-picker-and-it-s    Why do u ask same Question and waste our time ?